# Spec is not hitting the controller action in Rails API project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I have a request spec where it should hit the show action in the AnagramsController.

This is what my routes file looks like
`resources :anagrams, only: [] do
    get '/', to: 'anagrams#show', on: :collection
  end`

When I rake my routes I can see that I have the route I want:
`anagrams GET    /anagrams(.:format)  anagrams#show`

I run my request spec that looks like this

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Anagram API", type: :request do

  describe "GET /anagrams" do
    context "fetch for words with anagrams" do

      it "finds the anagrams" do
        get "/anagrams", params: {word: ["read"]}
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(["dare", "dear"])
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect the test to hit the show action in my controller

```
class AnagramsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    word_passed_in = params[:word].first
    results = AnagramFinder.fetch_anagrams(word_passed_in)
    end
    json_response(results)
  end

  private
  def anagram_params
    params.require(:word)
  end

end
```

However, when I run the spec, I see this:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Anagram API GET /anagrams fetch for words with anagrams finds the anagrams
     Failure/Error: expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(["dare", "dear"])

     JSON::ParserError:
       757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
           <title>SyntaxError at /anagrams</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <style>
           /* Basic reset */
           * {
               margin: 0;
               padding: 0; and on and on and on
```

I have a binding.pry in the show action in the controller and the spec isn't hitting the pry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the full code but you have an extra end in your show action

```
 def show
    word_passed_in = params[:word].first
    results = AnagramFinder.fetch_anagrams(word_passed_in)
    end
    json_response(results)
  end
```

Should be

```
 def show
    word_passed_in = params[:word].first
    results = AnagramFinder.fetch_anagrams(word_passed_in)

    json_response(results)
  end
```